# Delete confirmation button in UITableView overlaps the content

Tags: iphone

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *LogCellId = @"LogCellId";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:LogCellId];

    UILabel *lblSummary;

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:LogCellId] autorelease];   
        lblSummary = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 320.0, 30.0)] autorelease];
        lblSummary.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14];
        lblSummary.tag = SUMMARY_TAG;
        lblSummary.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
        lblSummary.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;

        [cell.contentView addSubview:lblSummary];
    } else {
        lblSummary = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:SUMMARY_TAG];
    }

    lblSummary.text = [self.logList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    return cell;
}
```

What I have there is just a simple cell with one label. I have added swipe-to-delete functionality but the delete button overlaps the label, not pushing it to side.

So I need help. I would appreciate an answer on how I would do this one and also how the autoresizing masks work. I do not feel comfortable with them at all, neither when or where I should use the autoresizing subviews.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I asked this question 3 months ago; with no helpful answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390583/resize-uitableviewcell-content-when-delete-button-shows-up.

Comment: @GendoIkari I found a solution and have responded to your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try combining different masks with the C bitwise OR operator: `|`. Experiment with the different masks, maybe this works:

```
lblSummary.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
```

Autoresizing masks are used when a `UIView` needs to be resized. By for instance using `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin`, you tell the view that you would like it to expand or shrink from or to that left margin, but not reposition the margin.

You would set `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin` like this in IB:

[image: IB]