# How to add a subview to a UIView's contentView in a UIStoryboard? (iOS)

Tags: ios, uiview, uitableview, uistoryboard

I have a UITableView that I've created in a UIStoryboard. It contains one Prototype UITableViewCell. The cells are populated in the ViewController's `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

I'm now trying to add the ability to delete cells using `commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:`. Everything is working except that when the delete button animates over the cell, the rest of the content doesn't shift over and it looks really ugly. According to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390583/resize-uitableviewcell-content-when-delete-button-shows-up), content will only be shifted if it's added to the cell's contentView rather than to the cell itself.

As such, **is there a way to add a UIView (Ex. a UIButton) to a UITableViewCell's contentView within a UIStoryboard?**

Comment: Adding a subview to the cell in IB does add it to the contentView, even though that doesn't show up in IB. The problem (in iOS 6 anyway) is that the constraints the system adds are to the cell rather than the contentView as they should be. So, for iOS 6, you have to add the subviews in code to the contentView, and also add the constraints in code to the contentView. I think this has been fixed in iOS 7.

Comment: I've decided to go with a different approach. Thanks for your answer. If you post it as an answer to the question I will accept it.

Comment: In Xcode 5.0, the table view's content view appears in Interface Builder and is a valid constraint target.